# How to select id when same id has multiple rows but I am looking for id which are missing a particular value

Tags: sql

I have this table my_table_c with the below values

SELECT * FROM my_table_c

```
ID  GROUP_ID      GROUP_VALUE 
1       2                   1 
3       3                   2 
3       4                   1 
5       4                   1 
5       2                   1 
2       2                   2 
2       3                   2 
2       4                   1
```

I am looking for this output where I get only the ID which do not have group_id 2. Additionally, I don't want to get the ID where group_id  2 is absent but other group ids are present.

If group_id  2 is absent, that's my target id.

So with the values shown in table above, I just expect ID = 3 to be returned as other ids 1, 5 and 2 each have rows where group_id = 2.

Can anyone please help with a query to fetch this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get all the id's that have group_id = 2 and use `NOT IN`

```
select *
from my_table_c
where id not in (select id from my_table_c where group_id = 2)
```

Another way but using `NOT EXISTS`

```
select *
from my_table_c mtcA
where not exists (select * 
                    from my_table_c mtcB 
                    where mtcA.id = mtcB.id and mtcB.group_ID = 2)
```